# Maven properties as environment variables

Tags: maven, log4j

Is it possible to reference maven properties (artifactId, groupId, etc) outside of the pomfile?  I am looking to specify the project's artifactId in my log4j file, and it would be nice to configure log4j.properties as follows:

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File"
        value="${artifactId}.log" />
</appender>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `log4j.properties` is a *resource* which will be *filtered* during maven build, then this is possible.

To elaborate, if `log4j.properties` is placed in `src/main/resources` and [filtering](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) is enabled for the resources, then `${project.artifactId}` will be replaced by maven during build with the artifact value.

Outside this use case, the property value will not be available automatically.